# MySql parameter in c# returns null with MS Sync Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio-2010, synchronization

Hi Im trying to create a sync class using the MS Sync Framework

the same code is used with NPGSQL (Postgresql) is working fine but when used with mysql it returns null

```
        // select new anchor command                
        string queryString = "SELECT MAX(idx) FROM (SELECT MAX(created) AS idx FROM product UNION SELECT MAX(updated) AS idx FROM product) as tmp";
        MySqlCommand anchorCmd = new MySqlCommand(queryString, serverConnection);
        MySqlParameter param_newAnchorVariable = new MySqlParameter("@" +
        SyncSession.SyncNewReceivedAnchor, MySqlDbType.DateTime);

        anchorCmd.Parameters.Add(param_newAnchorVariable).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        serverSyncProvider.SelectNewAnchorCommand = anchorCmd;

        //ONLY TO TEST IF Parameter is Retrieving OK ---------------------------------->
        serverConnection.Open();
        anchorCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(param_newAnchorVariable.Value.ToString());
        serverConnection.Close();
```

any help would be appreciated 
cheers